# Refresh postgres materialized view using scheduler

Tags: postgresql, azure, cron, scheduler, materialized-views

I was trying to figure-out how we can schedule to refresh the **materialized view** on **azure postgres database single server** which is in azure cloud, one solution is to use **pg_cron** extension, but it
seems it is only available on **azure flexible postgres database server** and not on **azure postgres database single server**, I did not get any other option available, any suggestion in this regard will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any postgres scheduler extension for the db hosted on Azure, so created one microservice to schedule the db functions.

[**Example Link**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)